# Play-java 2.5.9 form.errorsAsJson() always returns english error messages

Tags: java, playframework

I'm new to play framework, I'm using play java 2.5.9
I'm trying to get form errors and render it using ajax (that's why I'm using form.errorsAsJson()) , errors should be displayed in Arabic language

I've tried and put error messages in my conf/messages.ar like this:

```
#bean validation messages
validation.required=لابد من إدخال قيمة في هذا الحقل
error.required=لابد من إدخال قيمة في هذا الحقل
```

I've also tried and put the following in conf/ValidationMessages_ar.properties :

`error.required=\u0627\u0644\u062D\u0642\u0644 \u0645\u0637\u0644\u0648\u0628`
`validation.required=\u0644\u0627\u0628\u062F \u0645\u0646 \u0625\u062F\u062E\u0627\u0644 \u0642\u064A\u0645\u0629 \u0641\u064A \u0647\u0630\u0627 \u0627\u0644\u062D\u0642\u0644`
neither of the two messages is renderd but I always get:

```
This field is required
```

my action code is as follows:

```
@Transactional
public Result addUOMType(){
    ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();
    Form<UnitOfMeasureType> uomTypeForm = formFactory.form(UnitOfMeasureType.class);
    try{
        uomTypeForm = uomTypeForm.bindFromRequest();
        System.out.println(Http.Context.current()  != null ? Http.Context.current().lang() : "");
        if(uomTypeForm.hasErrors()){
            result.put("status", "error");
            result.put("errors", uomTypeForm.errorsAsJson());
            return ok(result);
        }
        UnitOfMeasureType uomType = uomTypeForm.get();
        uomType.save();
        result.put("status", "success");
        result.put("message", Messages.get("response.success"));
    }catch (Exception exp){
        result.put("status", "error");
        result.put("errors", Json.toJson(exp.getMessage()));
    }

    return ok(result);
}
```

the System.out.println prints:
Lang(ar)

Comment: <html lang="en"> in your main.scala.html?

Answer (score 2):

`Form.errorsAsJson` has an [overloaded version taking Lang parameter](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.9/api/java/play/data/Form.html#errorsAsJson-play.i18n.Lang-):

```java
public com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode errorsAsJson(Lang lang)
// Returns the form errors serialized as Json using the given Lang.
```

So you can do:

```java
result.put("errors", uomTypeForm.errorsAsJson(lang()));
```

and it will return properly localized messages, as long as you define them in `conf/messages.ar`. I've just tried this in my project and it worked fine.

Method `lang()` is [defined in `play.mvc.Controller`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.9/api/java/play/mvc/Controller.html#lang--).

Comment: Thanks Pawel for answering my question, it worked , do you know where I can find all message error keys? for example I put error.required it worked with `@Required` annotation , what should I use for `@Size` , I need list of all message keys please

Comment: @HassaanHassaan It seems there's a `message` field inside these annotations, so you can either [check in the documentation](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.9/api/java/play/data/validation/Constraints.MinLength.html#message--) or set your own value by passing `message` parameter to the annotation.

Comment: @HassaanHassaan You could also check [directly in the source](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.5.9/framework/src/play-java/src/main/java/play/data/validation/Constraints.java).

Comment: Bartkiewicz: I found that it even wroked without passing `Http.Context.current().lang()` parameter, all it needed is to just put the correct message keys/values in `conf/messages.ar` file

Answer (score 0):

Did you add `ar` to the supported languages in `conf/application.conf`?

Like this:

```
play.i18n.langs = [ "en", "ar" ]
```

Also, you can delete `conf/ValidationMessages_ar.properties` - you don't need this file.